# Don't implement position and animate from ng2-toastr in angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using ng2-toaster in angular4. I have implemented successfully. But some ToastOpton's feature such as animate, positionClass can not implement. I don't know what is the problem. My toast run successfully but not working of position and animate.

//ts file

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';
import {Toast, ToastsManager, ToastOptions} from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-snackbar',
  templateUrl: './snackbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./snackbar.component.css']
})

export class SnackbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public toastr: ToastsManager, vcr: ViewContainerRef) {
    this.toastr.setRootViewContainerRef(vcr);
  }
  showSuccess() {
    this.toastr.success('You are awesome!', 'Success!', {
      dismiss: 'click', 
      showCloseButton: false,
      animate: 'flyLef',
      positionClass: 'toast-bottom-center'
    })
    .then((toast: Toast) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.toastr.dismissToast(toast);
       }, 3000);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

//html file

```
<button class="btn btn-default" (click)="showSuccess()">Toastr 
Tester</button>
```

Comment: Have you imported the BrowserAnimationsModule into your AppModule? i.e. import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; then put it in the imports array

Comment: @RossScott i have imported that at app.module.ts

Comment: did you find a solution ? I experience the same issue here

Comment: @banibanc No, I did't find the solution. Now i am using mat-snackbar from angular material 2